# When should I use "Might" and "Might Be Able"

Tags: modal-verbs

What is the difference between these sentences?

> I might be able to finish work today
>
> I might finish work today
>
> He might come today
>
> He might be able to come today

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

> I might **be able** to finish work today.

The key thing here is to notice that *be able* denotes your ability. The modal verb **might** connects to **be able**, not only to **be**.

By adding **be able** on top of some modal verb like **might**, you judge your ability to finish work today:

> I will **be able** to finish work today. (I believe that I will be able to do it)
>   I will not **be able** to finish work today. (I believe that I will not be able to do it)
>   I should **be able** to finish work today. (I have an obligation to have the ability to do it)
>   I would **be able** to finish work today if you give me the materials. (A conditional sentence)

In the sentence

> I might **finish** work today.

The modal verb **might** connects to the verb **finish**. You estimate the possibility of finishing work today, but you do not mention your ability. As a results of this, the statement is less uncertain.

The same holds true for

> He might **come** today. (On the other hand, he might not - but we don't say that that's because of his **inability**)
>   He might **be able** to come today. (On the other hand, he might even be unable to come!)

The **be able** thing could be used to make a polite refusal:

> Sorry, I might not **be able** to come today. (There is a possibility that I will not come to visit you, but that would be because of my **inability**, not because I don't want to).

Answer (score 0):

The "might be able" forms suggest that whether he manages to finish or come depends, at least in part, on him (specifically, his ability)

The simpler "might" forms simply say nothing about what finishing/coming depends on. Maybe it is his ability, but maybe it's an approaching asteroid not hitting the earth. We just don't know.